# Pandas style based on logarithm of value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I'd like to style a Pandas DataFrame display with a background color that is based on the logarithm (base 10) of a value, rather than the data frame value itself.   The numeric display should show the original values (along with specified numeric formatting), rather than the log of the values.

I've seen many solutions involving the `apply` and `applymap` methods, but am not really clear on how to use these, especially since I don't want to change the underlying dataframe.

Here is an example of the type of data I have.  Using the "gradient" to highlight is not satisfactory, but highlighting based on the log base 10 would be really useful.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

E = np.array([1.26528431e-03, 2.03866202e-04, 6.64793821e-05, 1.88018687e-05,
       4.80967314e-06, 1.22584958e-06, 3.09260354e-07, 7.76751705e-08])

df = pd.DataFrame(E,columns=['Error'])
df.style.format('{:.2e}'.format).background_gradient(cmap='Blues')
```

[image: Pandas style using gradient of value]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use the `apply` function to do exactly what I want.  And also, I discovered a few more features in Matplotlib's colors module, including `LogNorm` which normalizes using a log.  So in the end, this was relatively easy.

What  I learned :

- Do not use `background_gradient`, but rather supply your own function that maps DataFrame values to colors. The  argument to the function is the dataframe to be displayed.   The return argument should be a dataframe with the same columns, etc, but with values replaced by colors, e.g. strings `background-color:#ffaa44`.
- Pass this function as an argument to `apply`.

```
import pandas as
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import colors, cm
import seaborn as sns

def color_log(x):
    df = x.copy()
    cmap = sns.color_palette("spring",as_cmap=True).reversed()
    
    
    evals = df['Error'].values
    norm = colors.LogNorm(vmin=1e-10,vmax=1)
    normed = norm(evals)

    cstr = "background-color: {:s}".format
    c = [cstr(colors.rgb2hex(x)) for x in cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]  
    
    df['Error'] = c
    return df

E = np.array([1.26528431e-03, 2.03866202e-04, 6.64793821e-05, 1.88018687e-05,
       4.80967314e-06, 1.22584958e-06, 3.09260354e-07, 7.76751705e-08])

df = pd.DataFrame(E,columns=['Error'])

df.style.format('{:.2e}'.format).apply(color_log,axis=None)
```

**Note (1)**   The second argument to the `apply` function is an "axis".  By supplying `axis=None`, the entire data frame will be passed to `color_log`.  Passing `axis=0` will pass in each column of the data frame as a Series.  In this case, the code supplied above will not work.  However, this would be useful for dataframes in which each column should be handled separately.

**Note (2)** If `axis=None` is used, and the DataFrame has more than one column, the color mapping function passed to `apply` should set colors for *all* columns in the DataFrame.  For example,

```
df[:,:] = 'background-color:#eeeeee'
```

would sets all columns to grey.   Then, selective columns could be overwritten with other colors choices.

I would be happy to know if there  is yet a simpler way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas 1.3.0, `background_gradient` now has a `gmap` (gradient map) argument that allows you to set the values that determine the background colors.

See the examples here (this link is to the dev docs - can be replaced once 1.3.0 is released) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient

Comment: Can the  `gmap`  argument be set to a function?

Comment: not yet but this is a good idea. will add it to the issues and see if I get round to implementing it.

Comment: On second thought, I wonder how useful this would be, given that "apply" is really flexible.   Maybe just better documentation on `apply`?   There is also an `applyfunc` which I didn't look too much into.

Comment: all of the built-in methods use apply. the purpose is to make the api more accessible for common functions, and not rely on apply to force common users to code everything themselves.